# Is it good to use high resistance to read 4-20 mA sensor output?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, current

I've seen several answers to this page related to this topic. Some answers suggested using a resistor to generate a voltage of the desired level. Some suggested using two optocouplers. I'm not interested in using optocouplers, so I want to skip those discussions.

The industrial transducers don't provide the schematic they use to generate 20mA output. So it's pretty uncertain for how much value of series resistance they can act as a constant current source. I may use 10 Ohm series resistor with a differential amplifier of 10x gain or 100 ohms resistor with a differential amplifier of 1x gain to get my expected voltage. Which one is better? The differential amplifier will be used to cut the 4mA offset.

Comment: I would advise against removing the 4 mA offset with a differential amplifier, because this current is there for a reason: It tells you that the sensor is actually connected and the wire is not broken. That can be quite important e.g. if your sensor is used to avoid turning a machine on while a person is still in the danger zone. Another reason is that with 4 mA a low sensor output is more noise resistant than at 0 mA, but this does not change with the differential amplifier.

Comment: @Grebu: Correct! Some smart current loop devices signal specific error conditions between 3.0 to 3.75 mA and between 22 to 24 mA, therefore I'd prefer dimensioning the input range accordingly just to be prepped for any chance (in multifunctional readout devices at least ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've learned that loop-powered current loop devices powered with 24 V are required to be able to drive 20 mA into 500 Ω loads which yields 10 V.

There are more details in IEC 60381-1 if you can access it.

This implies that every 24 V powered current loop device, even over long lines, should be able to be read via a resistor from 500 Ω down 0. If the loop voltage supply is less than 24 V the max. resistance may be smaller, and it depends on the voltage drop the loop powered sensor itself requires.

Example: your sensor requires 7 V to power itself (this should be stated in the datasheet), you have 80 Ω total wire resistance in the loop, and the loop is powered with 15 V.
What is the largest resistor allowed for measurement?

The loss due to wire resistance is 20 mA * 80 Ω = 1.6 V.
This leaves (15 - 7 - 1.6) V = 6.4 V (max) to be consumed by your readout circuit, so at 20 mA and 6.4 V you must not have more than 320 Ω measurement resistor value, you can freely choose a value below that as you like it.

So which one is better mainly is answered by the SNR you want, as long as the above limit is regarded.

I strongly recommend to prefer pulse-resistant resistors for measurement (it must withstand some 24 V pulses in worst case, for instance if the loop has interruptions or is closed after the power supply. The sensor can represent 0 Ω for a second or so). So this aspect tells to not go to the smallest resistor value.

In short: IMO higher is usually better, but stay below the limit.

*Edit2: Using two resistors in series can be useful to match the voltage to your ADC input range if it is only 1 V or so, and use the second resistor to limit power dissipation if the loop sensor has a failure.*

*Edit: keep in mind that some sensors use up to 24 mA for error signalling, so it may be wise to calculate with 24 mA in such cases.*

The story is a little different with self-powered loop devices. Here the sensor does only consume very little if any of the loop voltage. The rest remains valid though.

Answer (score 8):

> *Is it good to use high resistance to read 4-20 mA sensor output?*

4/20 mA transmitters use a series 24 volt supply. Quite a lot of  receivers use a 250 Ω resistor for the current to voltage conversion. I've seen a few that use less than 250 Ω. So, if you used 250 Ω in your receive circuit, it would drop 5 volts when 20 mA is flowing and not eat-into the 24 volt supply overhead too much. Example from [Elliot sound products 4-20mA Current Loop Basics](https://sound-au.com/appnotes/an011.htm): -

[image]

> *The differential amplifier will be used to cut the 4mA offset*

You don't need a differential amplifier to measure the voltage but you can use it to get rid of the offset (see the potentiometer and diff amp in the circuit above).

This circuit uses a 100 Ω sense resistor: -

[image]

Image from [INDUSTRIAL, 4-20 MA CURRENT LOOP, MEASURING CIRCUITS BASICS I](https://industrialcircuits.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/industrial-4-20-ma-current-loop-measuring-circuits-basics-i/). Both these sites also give details on transmitters.

Answer (score 7):

4-20mA two-wire transmitters from decent suppliers will always have a specification for how much voltage they need to work. To have a tangible example you can refer to [this](https://www.alphacontrols.com/Multimedia/www.alphacontrols.com/Files/ProductCategory/918/Data_sheet_MinIPAQ-L.pdf) random transmitter datasheet.

[image]

So this particular transmitter must have at least 8V across it at all times. You may also have a loop-powered indicator in the circuit which will drop additional voltage. A typical one might drop 5V maximum. [Here](https://www.ca.endress.com/en/field-instruments-overview/system-components-recorder-data-manager/loop-powered-indicator-RIA15?t.tabId=product-specification) is one that drops < 1V for analog indication. So if you had both, in this particular case, you might need 13V across indicator + transmitter. Subtract that from your power supply voltage and you have the maximum voltage your receiver can take. You should also allow for wire resistance if the runs are long.

Generally 24V is used for the transmitter power supply (lower voltages mean less power dissipation in the transmitter).

So if you have a 24V supply and this particular transmitter (no indicator) you can drop as much as 16V in the receiver. Really you'd want a few volts less than that so as not to have to worry about power supply tolerance, line resistance and so on.
Typically at least 5V is not a problem in the receiver.

Dropping a somewhat lower voltage than  your analog supply voltage can make protection easier. In industrial applications where precision is important and there is a lot of EMI and a wide temperature range a higher voltage is preferred for accuracy. The power dissipation in the precision receiver resistor can also come into play- a 250Ω resistor will dissipate 100mW at 20mA. But generally something in the 1V to 5V range is optimal, so 50Ω to 250Ω .

In lower accuracy applications with relatively high sense resistor you don't need an instrumentation amplifier or even a differential amplifier, but it's well worth considering the way the currents flow and trace resistances where accuracy and stability are important. If you have an ADC with more bits than you need and differential input it makes things easier to throw away some of the range for protection (or use a lower reference than the supply voltage and keep the bits) and use a Kelvin connection to the sense resistor.